# How can i capture down time between cluster crash and cluster spin up in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I  capture down time between cluster crash and cluster spin up in Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: I would guess that Stackdriver logging could be used to examine the major events detected by GCP.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use "[Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview)" in order to see the logs for any major event. In order to see the downtime of any specific resources you need to more specific with the "cluster crash".